# Escaping Backslash

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview for updating files in every row, that files are storaged in diferent folders depending of the values in gridview.

The gridview should allow download these files, and the folders with the files are in other location.

```
protected void gvwSACLot_Solic_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string server = System.Environment.MachineName.ToString();


    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvwSACLot_Solic.Rows)
    {
        string LotCliCod = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault().Text);
        string LotCajCod = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault().Text);
        int LotCajNum = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[2].Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault().Text);

        if (e.CommandName == "DescargarLot")
        {
            string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            if (filename != "")
            {

                string filepath = '\\' + server+ '\\' + "IMAGES" +
                LotCliCod + '\\' + LotCajCod + '\\' + LotCajNum + '\\' + filename;

                byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;   filename=" + filename);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I can't escape the backslashes (\).
I haved tried with single and double quotes.
I haved tried with "\\" and with @"\", but i can get the expected result.

when i debug i have this:
"\\ANGEL-DS\\IMAGES\\111\\JJJ\\1\\TEST"

what can i do for get a clean path?

please i hope anybody can help me

best regards.

Comment: Are you viewing the strings through the debugger, or outputting them somewhere? The debugger will display escape sequences the same way they are in code.

Comment: what is the value of `filepath when you use the debugger.. `"\\` is a clean path if you want to see single back slashes then use the string literal `@` or assign it like this `string @filepath = ......` ect

Comment: `filepath` is fine as-is. The debugger shows the escaped version of the string but if you print the value or get the length, you will see that the backslash character is included only once between the other fragments .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others said in the comments, the string is fine, but the debugger shows the escaped version of the string:

[image: String in debugger]

If you click on the magnifier icon, you will see the string without the escaping characters:

[image: String in text visualizer]

If you use your string later, e.g. by printing it to the console, the string will be displayed fine:

[image: String in console]

Comment: Thanks everybody,
You right, if I use the string later, it displays fine, for example:

lblMensaje.Text = @"\\" + servidor + '\\' + "IMAGES" +
                    LotCliCod + '\\' + LotCajCod + '\\' + LotCajNum + '\\';


BUT, when I try to use this value, again the value in filepath is not fine:
string filepath = "" + lblMensaje.Text;
byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

It's converted again t incorrect.

Comment: But, If I do what you suggest, It worked.
Thanks a lot everybody